# How can I perform this mongoDB lookup aggregation faster?

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql, aggregation

I want to run the following mongoDB query on Robo 3T, But it takes for ever to bring out an outcome:

```
db.getCollection('check').aggregate([
{ 
    $match:
    {
        $and:
        [
            {datetime: { "$gt" : new ISODate("2019-07-01 01:00:10.000Z")}},
        ]
    }
},
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "workstation",
            localField: "deviceid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "workstation"
        }    
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$workstation", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},    
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: "server",
            localField: "deviceid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "server"
        }    
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$server", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},  

{
     $lookup: 
        {
            from: "site",
            let: {
                ssiteid : "$server.siteid",
                wsiteid : "$workstation.siteid"
            },
            pipeline: [
                { $match:
                    { $expr: {                            
                        $or: [
                            {$eq : ["$_id","$$ssiteid"]},
                            {$eq : ["$_id","$$wsiteid"]}
                        ]
                        }                                                
                    }                                               
                }],                
            as: "site"
        }      
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$site", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},  

{
     $lookup: 
        {
            from: "client",
            localField: "site.clientid",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "client"
        }      
},
{
    $unwind: {path: "$client", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}
},

{ $project: { 
    "_id": 1, 
    "description": 1, 
    "extra": 1,
    "datetime": 1,
    "cname" : "$client.name",    
    "apiKey" : "$client.apiKey",
    "workstation": 1 ,
    "server":1
    }    
},

{ $match: 
    { "client.apiKey":"ae0a4c75230afae756fcfecd3d2838cf"}
},

 {$limit: 30}
])
```

However, if I remove the last match, then it takes 2 seconds to give the result!!

As the content of the collections, the following is check collection:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c1bbcfbfe78c90007af2676"),
"_class" : "dsadsa.ewrwer.werew,
"deviceid" : 943955,
"checkid" : "23303140",
"description" : "fdskfhsdj kfsdjfhskdjf hksdjfhsd kjfs",
"checkstatus" : "testerror",
"datetime" : ISODate("2018-12-04T15:55:00.000Z"),
"smsalerts" : 0,
"emailrecoveryalerts" : 1,
}
```

and site collection:

```
{
"_id" : 126581,
"_class" : "dsadsa.ewrwer.werew,
"clientid" : 94011,
"name" : "dsadas, dsadsa",
"connectionOk" : 1,
"primaryRouter" : "",
"secondaryRouter" : "",
"lastUpdate" : ISODate("2018-01-02T13:00:04.713Z"),
"enabled" : false
}
```

and client :

```
{
"_id" : 96763,
"_class" : "dsadsa.ewrwer.werew,
"name" : "JOhn Smith",
"viewDashboard" : 0,
"viewWkstsnAssets" : 0,
"dashboardUsername" : "none",
"timezone" : "",
"creationDate" : ISODate("2017-02-09T23:00:00.000Z"),
"serverCount" : 0,
"workstationCount" : 0,
"mobileDeviceCount" : 0,
"deviceCount" : 0,
"apiKey" : "dsaawedsa",
"lastUpdate" : ISODate("1970-03-17T11:00:00.000Z"),
"enabled" : false
```

}

Is there any way to perform a query like this (or similar ones) faster?

Also, is there any faster way than the GUI-based Robo mongo to access mongoDB?

Comment: Can you show your collection schema? that will help us to find out why it is taking so much time.

Comment: Please post the db.collection.explain().aggregate(...) for this aggregation. It would show the mongo's strategy behind executing the statement.

Comment: $lookup is used thrice, in your query which will have a drastic impact on the performance. Lookup is similar to performing a left outer join in RDBMS world. I would recommend you to redesign your schema with non normalized data.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath Do you mean modifying the Database? I have read access only!

Comment: Sorry for that, Try out with the person who is having modifying access. IN this case redesigning the schema will have a lot of improvement in the performance. The collections in the existing design are looking like normalized tables.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath regardless of redesigning the schema, what if I extract all of the database to a local drive? then, would it be easier to extract data out of it using python for instance?
In fact, the data could have been stored in SQL database instead of mongoDB!

Comment: So in that case, you can post here a sample document from each collection involved in this query and your expected output. That will help the people viewing this post to better understand the problem

Comment: @ClementAmarnath I added examples of checks, site, and client collections.

Answer (score 1):

Always create index in mongodb for the fields in reference table for which you are performing lookup, it will reduce the time of execution for query.

Comment: How long would it take to create a new index for a collection of 700 million entries with 15 fields?